# How do I set Environmental variable for my application while profiling it under visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, profiling, profiler

I have an application. I compile it using vs2008 team system. 
To run this app some certain environmental variables need to be set, such as SYSTEM_MODULE_PATH. My app loads system modules from there. Without this variable it wont run.
So When I profile it, I want to set this variable so that my application runs properly.

Now my question is, Where do I set this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it when I asked it. But didn't shared. Here is what I did.

I created a batch (.cmd) file. I set up my environment variable there. Then started *Visual Studio* using `devenv` command. Here is the sample batch file

```
rem Sample Environment loader for VS
SET ENV_VAR1=Value1
SET ENV_VAR2=Value2
SET ENV_VAR3=Value3
devenv \path\to\solution\file
```

Now *Visual Studio* opens with some ENV variable loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Start -> Control Panel -> System -> advanced Tab -> Environment variables

or 
CMD -> SET [variable=[string]]

Comment: I dont want to set env for whole system :P